# terminal minimize missing in 22.4.1

Tags: command-line

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04.1 to 22.04.1 I can no longer minimize terminal windows using alt-spacebar-enter.  The alt-spacebar menu formerly had 'minimize' as the top (default) item; now it's been changed to 'take screenshot' and there is no minimize item in the menu.

Is there a way to either restore the former minimize menu item, or another keyboard command to minimize terminal windows in 22.04.1?

Comment: The new menu does have Restore and Hide.  Alt space downarrow enter might work for you (if it's hide you want).

Comment: Really horrible decision putting "take a screenshot" as first item instead of "hide"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or another keyboard command to minimize terminal windows in 22.04.1?

The shortcut to minimise a Terminal (or other) window in Ubuntu is <kbd>Super+h</kbd>

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> on its own will display minimised windows for selection.

Finally, you can use <kbd>Super+Tab</kbd> to cycle through the minimised windows by continuing to press <kbd>Super</kbd> and switching minimised windows by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the one you want to restore is selected. Releasing the keys will restore that window.